# PCIe Risers not working on x1 but works on x16

Tags: hardware

I have some problem with my USB PCIe Risers for my Ethereum Mining Rig. I have 6 of them, 1 out of six is working perfectly fine when I plug the riser into x1 or x16 slot. However my other 5 risers work only when plugged into x16 slot, they do not work in x1 slot. I tried changing between pimpOS, Ubuntu and windows 10, no difference was made. I even tried using different GPUs too but to no avail. Below is my hardware list.

- MB -> Gigabyte H110-D3A
- CPU -> Intel Pentium G4400
- RAM -> 4GB Crucial
- SSD -> 120GB Sandisk
- GPU1 -> Zotac GTX 1070 mini (8GB)
- GPU2 -> Zotac GTX 1060 Amp (6GB)
- GPU3 -> MSI Radeon RX 570 (4GB)